# Repetition of there were

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:

> Loads of people were still about, of course there were: within yards of where he was walking there were four pubs which had just turned out: the Selkirk,the Fox the Angel and the Castle.

Why is 'there were' used twice?

Comment: What is the context and source of the quote?

Comment: It's a fiction book by Elizabeth Waite.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a nonstandard, informal usage, likely intended to replicate everyday speech. Normally, there would be an em dash (—) or  a semicolon after "still about" to make the break in the sentence clear.

Comment: Is there any grammatical significance of the repetition?

Comment: The two parts (which would normally be divided by a semicolon) are essentially separate sentences; if the word "were" weren't repeated, one of the sentences would lack a main verb.

Answer (score 0):

It is a carefully constructed usage.

The insertion of “of course there were:” is a usage designed to make the reader pause on the notion that there were lots of people about and to consider why that was easily explained (“of course” suggests there must be an easy and obvious explanation). The colon appears because it introduces a following thought, in this case the explanation for so many people. The explanation is that at the time of day the pubs had closed and all their customers were out on the street.